# d3js > Lazy load data ondemand

Tags: javascript, d3.js, lazy-loading

I'm currently using [Rob's](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033) `d3js` "collapsible tree" to render data relationships (so far so good!).

This works well with static data - however I'd like to dynamically retrieve and load 'child' relationships, when a leaf node is expanded (/clicked).

**e.g.**

> When `root` is expanded, and `ProjectA` is expanded, and the user
>   clicks the child `ProjectB`,
>   Then `ProjectB`'s children are (dynamically) loaded and displayed (and so on).

Reasons for wanting this behaviour:

- reducing upfront load of large/complex data structures
- rendering circular data structures

I'm currently reading through the [`d3js` API Docs](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md), however I can't see anyway of:

- specifying a dynamic datasource (e.g. a function, which given a parent, returns children)
- adding child nodes based on an event

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

**Example / WIP:** https://jsbin.com/davetij/edit?js,output

Answer (score 3):

Solved it, the solution was easier than I realised.

I created a function `lazyLoadChildren(..)` to dynamically populate a node's children (based on the node `name`)...

**i.e.**

```
const childrenLookup = {
    ProjectA: [
        {"name":"FOO"},
        {"name":"BAR"},
        {"name":"CAT"},
        {"name":"ProjectB"}
    ],
    ProjectB: [
        {"name":"FOO"},
        {"name":"BAR"},
        {"name":"CAT"},
        {"name":"ProjectA"}
    ]
}

const lazyLoadChildren = d => {
    const dynamicChildren = childrenLookup[d.name]
    if (isNotPresent(d.children) && isNotPresent(d._children) && isPresent(dynamicChildren)) {
        d.children = deepCopy(dynamicChildren)
    }
}
```

... then I invoked it for each child of a node, whenever the `expand(..)` function was called...

**i.e.**

```
function expand(d, recurseFlag) {
    if (d._children) {
        d.children = d._children;
        // lazy load all children (collapsed)
        d.children.forEach(x => {
            lazyLoadChildren(x)
            collapse(x)
        })
        if (recurseFlag === true) {
            d._children.forEach(x => expand(x, recurseFlag));
        }
        d._children = null;
    }
}
```

Here is the full example: https://jsbin.com/davetij/edit?output