# How to efficiently collapse a large d3.hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

My starting point is the collapsable tree from https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025.

I added a button at the top which collapses all nodes from the bottom up to the depth of 1.
In the javascript code the following three functions are added at the end:

```
    function eventListener() {
      const collapse = document.getElementById('input-collapse');
      collapse.onclick = function() {
          const t0 = performance.now();
          collapseTree();
          const t1 = performance.now();
          console.log("EventListener took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
      };
  }

  function collapseTree() {
    let alreadyCollapsed = false;
    root.eachAfter(node => {
      if (node.depth > 0) {
        alreadyCollapsed = node.children ? false : true;
        node.eachAfter(_node => collapse(_node));
        if (!alreadyCollapsed) {
          update(node);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function collapse(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
    }
```

The collapseTree function does what it should do, but pretty slowly. The collapse takes about 1 second.

I added two timers with `performance.now()` before and after the call of `collapseTree()` to approximately measure the duration. I was surprised that the timers clock about 80ms, which would be acceptable but is way less than the actual 1 sec on the user client side.

1. My understanding is optimizing the algorithm `collapseTree()` (which has n^2 runtime complexity) won't help much in terms of performance. Is that correct?
2. The performance bottleneck seems to come from the repeated update() calls. The code execution is finished in 80 ms, where does the delay come from - the DOM operations of such a large SVG?
3. What is in general a good way to look for such a performance problem? I used chrome developer dev tool --> performance but wasn't able to find the cause.

The complete code is here: https://codepen.io/ee2dev/pen/eYvLbOR

p.s. The repeated update calls are made to use the correct transition of each collapsed node to its parent node.

Comment: pps. the reason the algorithm collapseTree looks  strange is that initially the collapse was implemented collapsing all nodes down to the leaf. When I saw the bad performance I changed this part a bit so it effectively just collapses the depth 1 node. But the performance was not improved

Comment: The transition in the collapse/ expand has a `duration` parameter - try adjusting it ?

Comment: thanks! That's a valid point, but when I changed the transition duration to 0, there is still a delay. I will try to find a larger JSON, so its more evident

Comment: E.g. if I choose this file: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/EE2dev/plotAPI/plotAPI.json", it takes forever (instead of the one second clocked time

Comment: I looked also at the transition.delay(), but it defaults to 0

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959515/d3js-lazy-load-data-ondemand

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that. It seems come from rendering, since when it’s stuck just a part of the tree is rendered

Comment: Yep, I agree, it's the rendering and lazy loading probably not that much help. I used this same block as the basis for another question recently and noticed it 'jitters' on expand collapse which from reading another answer is maybe text being rendered on top of previous text so there's maybe something suboptimal about the block itself on top of D3 just slowing down with a really large dataset.